# Software or Python library to sync several audio files with each other

Tags: linux, audio, audio-editing

I have around 240 audio files (aiff) that start at a different millisecond. I need to make all of them start at the same millisecond. Lets say I need it all the audios to start at 0.005. How can I do it without having to edit one by one? Is there a Python library, or a software that can do it automatically?

Comment: Do you mean there is no audio for x milliseconds, and x varies for each file?  And you want x to be uniform for each file?

Comment: exactaly. Here i found a a command that attempts to normalize the  diferent start time of the exact sound files i'm working with :   ( https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/are-there-free-records-of-separate-piano-notes-in-wav-files-for-instance/22771#22771?newreg=8490e87d09674649b366d626e59e953b ) . And then i used a script to aply it to all the 240 files. But it didnt exactaly fix all of them, only some.

Comment: I guess im dreaming to much ... Unless there is a way to detect when the audio file have  the first sudenly increase of noise ( stops being silent), track the time between this moment and the moment 0, and then select part of the track based on its time, and cut/delete it ... I dont think it can be done.

Comment: Keep your hope up.  It's definitely possible to accomplish this programmatically.  (But I'm sorry, I'm not sure of which applications and/or libraries support this exact functionality.)